# is there any simple way to implement google speech api into my ios program?

Tags: ios, speech

Is there any simple way to implement `google speech api` into my ios program?

I just want user to push a -microphone shape button- (like they do in google chrome search )

I want to awake google speech api via java script.
 But if it is possible without having "a program wants to use your microphone do you let it use... " warning message 
(Because you know after several push it is annoying!)

Then I just want to get the recognised text into a text area

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: I've written a [library](http://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec) that uses the Google speech recognition API and runs on iOS.

Comment: thanks but I tried to use it and couldn't. Could you also explain little bit about usage of it?

Comment: @faithbarut There are examples in the "examples" folder, have you seen them?

Comment: The thing is, this way of google speech usage is not safe I think. Why? 1- If google changes something with an update it is very high risk that this method is not usable anymore 2- Apple may reject my program but if I use java script method which is provided by google apple may accept...

Comment: Anotherthing there is no .m file among them. How it can be an object c example?

Comment: @faithbarut It isn't. The library is written in C, and its interface is C too. Also, if you don't like how it's done, write another library. You're not forced to accept the helping hand.

Comment: what is your point? you dont answer any of above questions you just create new ones...

Comment: @faithbarut C is a subset of Objective-C. If you want to use a C library on iOS, you can just do it. Don't expect Objective-C examples to come with a C library.

Comment: and how can I call a C function from a C file and which function should I call first?

Comment: @faithbarut `the_function()`. [And here's the example.](https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec/tree/master/examples/simple.c)